# Views custom data source

Tags: views, social-network

I need to be able to display a Facebook album in my Drupal site. I have the FB integration done, and have the PHP code to pull down photos. To keep things clean, I don't want to write my own album functionality and shove that into Drupal - I'd rather just present to views the data I have pulled from FB and have views display it.

Is there any way to achieve this? Most links I can find regarding custom views assume you are querying a database.